# How to keep my mind clear during competitive math exams

Tags: mathematics, exams

I've been training for the mathematical olympiad for a while now and from what I've gathered from my past exams, I feel like I'm alright in terms of knowing my theorems and formulae, but I struggle to keep my mind clear during the exams. By that, I mean I can solve 2 or 3 problems, then for the rest of the exam I can't seem to concentrate and think properly, especially if I'm in a time crunch. In my most recent olympiad exam, I solved only half of the problems which I should've been able to solve because I wasn't able to concentrate after solving 2-3 problems (Yet, I was able to solve almost the entire question set fairly easily at home). Anyone know how I can tackle this?

Comment: It seems to me as if the problem with the question is that the context is not about academia. If you change it from the mathematical olympiad to exams in general, I believe that it would be on topic - there are certainly enough people who have similar problems in university. I'm pretty new here myself, however, so take this with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 2):

The combination of time pressure and pressure for results can be a lot of stress. What often helps is to get familiar with the situation causing the stress, but with lower stakes.

Personally I find it helps me a lot if

1. I know that I am capable of solving that kind of problem
2. I have a good feeling for how long I can spend on a single problem

Now it sounds like you already have point 1 covered.

So get used to the time pressure. When you are practicing don't just solve the problems, also set yourself a hard deadline. Evaluate your results once the time runs out, not once you have solved everything. Try to find a balance between speed and results.

If practicing on your own doesn't cause you enough pressure you can raise the stakes otherwise (I find my own pride usually does it for me).
For example you can practice together with friends who also want to participate in the exam. Do a mock exam and grade each other. Compete for bragging rights or for whoever has to buy the pizza.

Or maybe for you it's some other aspect that causes the stress - for example the location or the amount of people around you. Try to figure out what it is and replicate it when you're preparing.